# Wildcards Not Working in Excel Mac Filters Dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, office-for-mac

Can anyone please explain to me why this doesn't work in my Mac version of Excel when the same thing works on the Windows version? I've tried the (?) and (*) wildcard characters, and I can't find anything online that says this shouldn't work as expected.

[image: Screenshot of Excel Filter Search]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using the following.

[image]

Comment: This works, oddly, haha, thank you!